# read data from SQLite database using AsyncTask on button press

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

Not very familiar with SQLite databases but I've gone through some tutorials/SO posts and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Currently I want to save data on a button press and then read the data onto another activity in table form.

Here is my attempt at creating the database:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static int    DB_VERSION = 10;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "workout.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Workout_Log";
    public static final String COLUMN_DISTANCE = "Distance";
    public static final String COLUMN_SPEED = "Speed";
    public static final String COLUMN_DURATION = "Duration";

public static final String SQL_CREATE_WORKOUT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        COLUMN_DISTANCE + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_SPEED + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_DURATION + " REAL NOT NULL );";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_WORKOUT_TABLE);
}
```

Here is where I save the data on button press:

```
   private class WriteToDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
            // Gets the data repository in write mode
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_DISTANCE, distance);
                values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_CADENCE, roundedLeft + roundedRight);
                values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_DURATION, leftTime + rightTime);
            } finally {
                    db.close();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

While calling the Async function in my onClickListener:

```
//Saves on Click?
                    WriteToDB writeToDB = new WriteToDB();
                    writeToDB.execute();
```

I believe it is saved, correct me if I'm wrong, so I try to read and set a TextView to the value in the database(to check if it works):

```
private class ReadFromDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
            // Gets the data repository in write mode
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            String[] projection = {
                    BaseColumns._ID,
                    DBHelper.COLUMN_DISTANCE,
                    DBHelper.COLUMN_CADENCE,
                    DBHelper.COLUMN_DURATION
            };

            Cursor cursor = db.query(
                    DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            float itemId = cursor.getFloat(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.COLUMN_DISTANCE)
            );
            val = Float.toString(itemId);
            cursor.close();

            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I press the button to access it I get an error:

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where exactly are you writing to DB in WriteToDB async task? as I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `doInBackground` just preparing `ContentValues` for inserting in db but not calling `SQLiteDatabase.insert` method for adding new row in database:

```
long rowID=db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

And on Button press getting :

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Error because `cursor` is empty.

To avoid this error use `Cursor.getCount()` to check Cursor object contains rows or not before reading from it.

Comment: I guess the better question is what do I do with the rowID after I create it?

Comment: @thenry: No, rowID is just for checking is row successfully inserted or not. if not inserted then rowID will be `-1`

Comment: thanks for the help, it no longer gives an error. But I don't think that the DB is being populated because when I set the TextView it is blank. Is there a problem that you see?

Comment: @thenry: check what value getting in `val = Float.toString(itemId);` this line

Comment: val is getting null, so that explains it, I also checked itemId which is getting 0.0 so COLUMN_DISTANCE must not be getting the distance value expected (I checked distance and it is 10). Does this have to do with me returning null at the end of doInBackground?

Comment: @thenry: No, what value getting in `rowID` when inserting row?

Comment: It's 12 right now but it increments by 1 every time I call WriteToDB